# Crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS only on device

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, visionkit

I am getting crash on button click

```
        let requester = VNRecognizeTextRequest { request, error in
            guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else {
                fatalError("Received invalid observations")
            }
            
            for observation in observations {
                guard let bestCandidate = observation.topCandidates(1).first else {
                    print("No candidate")
                    continue
                }
                if bestCandidate.string.contains(".") {
                    self.allTextString.append(" \(bestCandidate.string)")
                }
                print("Found this candidate: \(bestCandidate.string)")
            }
            if self.allTextString == "" {
                 self.showActionSheetTitleMessageOnMainThread("Temperature not found", message: "")
            } else {
                 self.TempratureValue.text = self.allTextString
            }
           
        }
        
        let requests = [requester]
```

While creating an array of the requester variable.     On Simulator code works fine.  And memory to requester is allocated ,  But when running on device requester memory is uninitialised.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L36f.png)

Comment: See if these links are of any help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225412/exc-bad-access-in-device-not-in-simulator and https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/exc-bad-access-crash/

Comment: Also checkout this - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118520